# Gitlab pull mirror option is disabled for Gitlab EE 12.8.5-ee Ultimate

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, mirroring

I am trying to use gitlab `mirror repository` functionality of gitlab but under `Mirror direction`, it only shows `push` option to me, dropdown menu is greyed out. I can not select `pull` option.
Gitlab version : Gitlab EE 12.8.5-ee Ultimate.
My user account is maintainer.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

After searching a bit on this got the answer why the pull option was disabled:

Answer :

1. It appears that the ability to disable mirrors was introduced in GitLab 10.3
2. So after upgrading gitlab, Admin has to specifically **Enable mirror configuration**

Enable single checkbox in Admin -> Application Settings -> Repository:

[image: Enable mirror configuration]

If this checkbox is unchecked, even project owners can't administer mirrors, though the text only says push mirrors.

Reference : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/13769

Comment: What about repos of non-paying users in gitlab.com? There's no Admin section there, as far as I can tell. Did they turn mirroring into an EE feature?

Answer (score 0):

From [Repository Mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html)

- check if the repo was not *already* configured for pushing (and can no longer be modified for pulling)
- some prerequisite might prevent any pulling option.